# How do I mutate across to multiple columns together that have similar names in R?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, mutate, across

I have many columns that have same names that always start with the same string, either n_ for the number of students, score_ for the percent of students who passed, and loc_ for the room number.

In this, I want to multiple the n_ columns with their respective score_ columns (so n_math * score_math, n_sci * score_sci, etc.) and create new columns called n_*_success for the number of students who passed the class.

If I had just a few columns like in this sample dataset, I would do something like this for each column:

```
mutate(n_sci_success = n_sci * score_sci)
```

But I have many columns and I'd like to write some expression that will match column names.

I *think* I have to use regex and across (like across(starts_with("n_)), but I just can't figure it out.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's a sample dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- tibble(id = c(1:4),
               n_sci = c(10, 20, 30, 40),
               score_sci = c(1, .9, .75, .7),
               loc_sci = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
               n_math = c(100, 50, 40, 30),
               score_math = c(.5, .6, .7, .8),
               loc_math = c(4, 3, 2, 1),
               n_hist = c(10, 50, 30, 20),
               score_hist = c(.5, .5, .9, .9),
               loc_hist = c(2, 1, 4, 3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `across` and new `pick` function from `dplyr` 1.1.0

```
library(dplyr)

out <- test %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('n_'), .names = 'res_{col}') * 
           pick(starts_with('score_')) * pick(starts_with('loc_')))

out %>% select(starts_with('res'))

#  res_n_sci res_n_math res_n_hist
#      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1      10          200         10
#2      36           90         25
#3      67.5         56        108
#4     112           24         54
```

This should also work if you replace all `pick` with `across`. `pick` is useful for selecting columns, `across` is useful when you need to apply a function to the columns selected.

I am using `across` in the 1st case (with `starts_with('n_')`) is because I want to give unique names to the new columns using `.names` which is not present in `pick`.

Comment: thanks! Quick question--how does pick() know to match the columns together? For instance, when I look at it, my (limited) understanding would suggest that R would think to multiple ALL n_ rows by ALL score_ rows and ALL loc_ rows, but that's clearly not the case. Is it because of the col argument?

Comment: `pick` does not match the columns, it just selects them. It requires the columns to have specific order either all `sci` columns should be together (like in the example) or all `n`, `score`, `loc` should be together.

Answer (score 2):

`pick()` is very nice, thanks for sharing. Here is way using `reduce` from `purrr` package:

We first use `split.default` to get a list, then apply `reduce` via `map_dfr`:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
test %>%
  split.default(str_remove(names(.), ".*_")) %>% 
  map_dfr(reduce, `*`)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
   hist    id  math   sci
  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10     1   200  10  
2    25     2    90  36  
3   108     3    56  67.5
4    54     4    24 112
```

Comment: Plius one for the `split.default() %>% reduce()` idea! Need to play around with that :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use {dplyover} to solve this kind of problems.
Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer and the package is not on CRAN.

We have two options:

The easiest way is to use `dplyover::across2()`. Below I use `dplyr::transmute()` to only show the newly created columns, but we can use `mutate()` instead to add the new columns to our `data.frame`.

`across2()` lets you specify two sets of columns to loop over. Here we choose all columns that `starts_with("n_")` and all columns that `starts_with("score_")`. We can then use `.x` (for the former) and `.y` (for the latter) in the `.fns` argument. In the `.names` argument we can specify how our new names should look like. We take the name of the first column `{xcol}` and add `_success` to it.

```r
library(dplyover) # https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/

test %>% 
  transmute(
    across2(starts_with("n_"),
           starts_with("score_"),
           ~ .x * .y,
           .names = "{xcol}_success")
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   n_sci_success n_math_success n_hist_success
#>           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1          10               50              5
#> 2          18               30             25
#> 3          22.5             28             27
#> 4          28               24             18
```

While this approach is easy and straightforward there is one problem: it assumes that the columns are in the correct order. This is also an assumption of the other two answers. If we have a large `data.frame` and are not sure if really all columns are in the correct order, `dplyover::over()` is the better and programmatically safe option.

Here we loop over a string and use this to construct the variable names. Within `over()` we use `cut_names("^.*_")` to get the stems of the variable names, in our example `c("sci", "math", "hist")`. Then in the function in `.fns` we construct the variable names by wrapping a string inside `.()` (to evaluate it as a variable name). Within the string we can use `{x}` to access the string of the current iteration. This approach will always combine `n_sci` with `score_sci` even if the columns are not ordered correctly. Finally, here too we can create nice names on the fly in the `.names` argument.

```r
test %>% 
  transmute(
    over(cut_names("^.*_"), # <- gets us c("sci", "math", "hist")
         ~ .("n_{.x}") * .("score_{.x}"),
         .names = "n_{x}_success"
           )
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   n_sci_success n_math_success n_hist_success
#>           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1          10               50              5
#> 2          18               30             25
#> 3          22.5             28             27
#> 4          28               24             18
```

Data from OP

```r
library(tidyverse)

test <- tibble(id = c(1:4),
               n_sci = c(10, 20, 30, 40),
               score_sci = c(1, .9, .75, .7),
               loc_sci = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
               n_math = c(100, 50, 40, 30),
               score_math = c(.5, .6, .7, .8),
               loc_math = c(4, 3, 2, 1),
               n_hist = c(10, 50, 30, 20),
               score_hist = c(.5, .5, .9, .9),
               loc_hist = c(2, 1, 4, 3))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Sure `dplyover::across2()` -> fantastic!